# Functional Equations Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that for any irrational number $r$, and any real number $x$ we have $f(x)=f(x+r)$. Show that $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: What happens when you plug in $x=0$? Can you show that $f$ is constant over all irrational numbers and coincides with $f(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=0$ then $f(0)=f(r)$, for any $r$ irrational.

Now take $x=p/q\in \Bbb Q$ then $p/q+r \notin \Bbb Q$ so $$f\left(\frac{p}{q}+r\right)=f(0)$$ but $$f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=f\left(\frac{p}{q}+r\right)=f(0)$$

So, $f(x)=f(0)$ for any $x \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is irrational, for $r=-x$ we have $f(x)=f(x-x)=f(0)$.

If $x$ is rational than, for $r$ irrational , $x+r$ is irrational and we have:
$f(x)=f(x+r)=f(0)
$

Answer (score 0):

Trivially $f$ is constant on irrationals (set $x=0$ with $f(r)=f(0)$ for all irrational $r$). Let $q$ be rational. Then $q-\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Hence $$f(q)=f(q-\sqrt{2})=f\bigl(q-\sqrt{2}-(q-\sqrt{2})\bigr)=f(0).$$ This gives us $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.